# Contact form block in CMS page not working

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, cms-block, contact-form

I made custom layout page for CMS page and i want to add Contact form in that CMS page.

For this i am using following code in CMS page content :

```
{{block type=”core/template” name=”contactForm” form_action=”{{store direct_url=”contacts”}}/index/post” template=”contacts/form.phtml”}}
```

But it showing code in front side not showing contact form. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use this in your cms page {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" 
form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}

Comment: I had also used that but not working always showing entered code not form.

Comment: can you please share your code(contact form code)

Comment: You can get help from here,I have also used same:- <br>
http://inchoo.net/magento/contact-form-in-magento/ <br>
or <br>
http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=50

Answer (score 2):

try this i think it " problem..

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: your given code is also not working it is only displaying /index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}

Comment: update check it now...

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code in your CMS page in Magento.

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Let me know if you face any further query with this.

Comment: I am using this code with multiple store and multiple sore views so i need to store code before "contacts/index/post" like "eu_en/contacts/index/post" but it will be not good put static store code for all store. Please provide me if any other solution.